# push a value into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="big-bus-right-part" id="bis-bus-first-floor">               
  <div id="posB100" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB101" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB102" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB103" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB104" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB105" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB106" class="vehicle-seat selected" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)">1</div>
  <div id="posB107" class="vehicle-seat selected" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)">2</div>
</div>
```

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent = function (el) {
  if ($(el).text().length > 0) {
      $(el).toggleClass('selected');    
  }

  var array = new Array();
  var frontSeats = new Array();
  var selectedSeats = $('#bis-bus-first-floor').find('.vehicle-seat.selected').html();
  console.log(selectedSeats);

  frontSeats.push(selectedSeats);
  console.log(frontSeats);
}
```

What I want to do is grap all the values that have the **selected** class into the html (see values 1 and 2 in the html) and push them into the array..

Comment: Try using `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: You'll have to iterate, but why do you want the HTML, why not just the elements themselves, wich jQuery gives you in an array-like object anyway ?

Comment: How do the 1 and 2 get there? What if the user clicks one of the others that doesn't have anything in it?

Comment: Change `new Array()` to `[]` as it's significantly faster, and also easier to type.

Comment: Separately, I'd recommend using jQuery to hook up the event handler rather than using an `onclick` attribute. For one thing, then you don't have to make the handler global, and you'd probably also benefit from using delegated handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var frontSeats = $('#bis-bus-first-floor')
                    .find('.vehicle-seat.selected')
                    .map(function() {
                        return $(this).html();
                    })
                    .get();
```

`frontSeats` will be an array containing `"1"` and `"2"`.

Example:

```js
var bc = {};
bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent = function (el) {
    if ($(el).text().length > 0) {
        $(el).toggleClass('selected');    
    }

    var frontSeats = $('#bis-bus-first-floor')
                        .find('.vehicle-seat.selected')
                        .map(function() {
                            return $(this).html();
                        })
                        .get();
    console.log(frontSeats);
};
```

```css
.vehicle-seat {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-bus-right-part" id="bis-bus-first-floor">               
  <div id="posB100" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB101" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB102" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB103" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB104" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB105" class="vehicle-seat" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)"></div>
  <div id="posB106" class="vehicle-seat selected" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)">1</div>
  <div id="posB107" class="vehicle-seat selected" onclick="bc.vehicleSeatFirstFloorHandleEvent(this)">2</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also::

```
(function (el) {
  if ($(el).text().length > 0) {
      $(el).toggleClass('selected');    
  }

  var frontSeats = [] 
  var selectedSeats = $('.selected').each(function(){
    frontSeats.push($(this).html());
    })
  console.log(frontSeats);
})()
```